# Глючит прокрутка horizontallscrollview

Tags: java, android

Совсем недавно начал делать свое приложение на Android, так сказать, набивать руку. Сейчас передо мной стоит следующая цель: сделать прокручиваемый горизонтальный список небольших карточек, внутри которых ImageView, для того чтоб пользователь мог выбрать одну из них. Но, при моей реализации, на моем устройстве, а это Nexus 7 2013, все глючит при скролле. Почему? 
XML:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/mixesLayout"></LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Java class: это мой метод для добавления карточки:

```
public void addCard(LinearLayout lay, int id) {
    CardView cards = new CardView(this);
    final ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
    final int name = id; // значение для Toast
    img.setImageResource(id);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(130, 130);
    cards.setLayoutParams(params);
    img.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(130, 130));
    ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams mlpShapes = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) cards.getLayoutParams();
    mlpShapes.setMargins(20, 0, 0, 0);
    cards.setCardElevation(5);
    cards.setRadius(5);
    cards.addView(img);
    cards.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getResourceEntryName(name), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    lay.addView(cards);
}
```

А это сами добавления карточек:

```
layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mixesLayout);
addCard(layout, R.drawable.apple);
addCard(layout, R.drawable.plum);
addCard(layout, R.drawable.apricot);
addCard(layout, R.drawable.pineapple);
addCard(layout, R.drawable.orange);
```

В коде их не 5, а 30 штук.

Кто-то может сказать в чем мой косяк? Где то он определенно есть, но я еще сырой и заметить не могу его) Буду благодарен, кто подтолкнет на путь истинный, с глючным скроллвью не хочется как то быть :(

Comment: используйте горизонтальный RecyclerView.